# Simple Matlab optimisation

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Given this problem, I was asked to optimise the code. I can't seem to find a way to make it run any quicker.

```
nmax= 2000;
mmax= 2000;
    for m=1:mmax
        for n=1:nmax
            A(n,m)= n+m;
        end 
    end
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Using [vectorization](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) you can simply write:

```
x = 1:2000;
A = x+x.';
```